# What are key factors when evaluating and comparing miniprep columns?

Tags: lab-reagents, minipreps

I'm looking to comparing different protocols for minipreps for plasmid DNA purification. What factors should I be looking at? A few things come to mind:

- Cost
- Yield
- Time per step
- Replacement with other reagents
- Spin vs. vacuum
- Color and caps or lack thereof

Comment: [Shopping advice is generally off-topic on all SE sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and a question about the current price of columns is very localized in time and geographically.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I would recommend re-framing this question in how to objectively evaluate columns for making your own column-based purification kits. I have some good advice for you if this question gets re-opened.

Comment: I would not focus on awesthetic aspects like colour and caps. They don't influence the overall process or yield, and are just nice marketing aspects. The real things to consider are purity of extraction, quality of column resin, % yield, salt removal, flexibility of kit reagents and overall time and relative costs.

Answer (score 3):

Storage conditions and shelf life are some of the things that you should consider in comparing columns.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have covered the essentials here. I can't think of anything else.

Since the Qiagen patent on spin prep columns ran out, these kits are very cheap - $0.40 each?  In the 3 or 4 kits Ive used, they all seem to use the same protocol and about the same buffers, so there might be differences in quality or yield but if so, they are small.

You can even make your own buffers [as the recipes are on open wet ware](http://openwetware.org/wiki/Qiagen_Buffers).  None of the kits i've used has suggested that these buffers can't be used.  They even usually call the buffers by the same names.

So your application would have be pretty discriminating to differentiate.  Even if this were the case, the quality could probably be improved a lot just by washing the column more.  Can you provide more details about how a few percent one way or another might be an issue?

Comment: I guess that it really doesn't matter. I guess we need to form a community wiki.

Comment: Congrats shigeta on being the first user to reach 5000 reputation!